# I keep getting Payment Instrument not valid when trying to import Contributions - after upgrade from LTS 4.6 to 5.3.x

Tags: civicontribute, import, data-import

We recently upgraded from LTS 4.6 to 5.3.1 (in July). Via the GUI we can see the Payment Method that we'd like to import -> Moneris -> id=6

[image]

**Importing with Payment Method:**

- Moneris -> fails: Reason: Payment Instrument is not valid: Moneris
- 6 -> fails: Reason: Payment Instrument is not valid: 6

What else can I try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok next thing to try is to check the `civicrm_option_value` table. Note it has a name column (in addition to what you can see in the GUI in 5.3.x). In the old days this name column was exposed and could be set independently: here it was set to `Offline Credit Card` - Importing with Payment method:

- Offline Credit Card -> works!

[image]

Comment: could you mark your answer as solved? That might help others as well.

Comment: SE only lets you accept your own answer in 2days

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT any idea why it is no longer exposed via the gui?

Comment: Not sure if it was intentional or by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Karen's answer above certainly showed me what is wrong. It seems that its edits the label and not the name but the check on import is to name and not label. Is this a bug? I am on CiviCRM 5.15.1 at present.

I sorted things out for me by deleting the Payment Method that was causing the problem and then recreating it. This was no problem for me as there were no existing contributions. Might have side effects in a mature site.

Update: deleting and re-inputting won't work for the "Check" Payment method as this is reserved and can't be deleted. So for this one I had to go in and change the database.

It looks like its fixed in 5.17.0 though... see https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1133

Answer (score 0):

This could also be a translation issue. After upgrading to 5.3.1 we had to change 'Cheque' to 'Check'. Haven't dug into that one yet.

Comment: Hi Andrew - I suspect that Translation perhaps changes Label but not Name. The importer definitively appears to match for Name (which is no longer exposed in the GUI)