# Mass cancelation of memberships

Tags: civimember, status

I have a list of some 700 email addresses that currently have a membership status of *Current*.  I'd like to change to a new Membership status I've created in Membership Status Rules called *Bouncing Cancelled*.

I've tried exporting doing it via an import:

```
"Email","Membership ID","Membership Start Date","Membership Type","Status Override","Status Override End Date","Membership Status"
"xxxx@yyyy.com","19201","2018-10-01","Member","1",,"Bouncing Cancelled"
```

And variations of that (like setting the just the status to just *Cancelled*), but regardless of what I do the import always fails with: `Invalid value for field(s) : Membership Status`.

Can suggest a different way?

Comment: I've done it now, using a convoluted semi manual processes.  I created a new field, set that field y1, y2 and so on so I could use search to locate them and then use "Update multiple memberships" to manually set the status for each contact.  Given this must be a common issue it seems like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

`Invalid value for field(s) : Membership Status` means that the csv file had invalid options for Membership status. The import file should use machine name rather label (or hopefully membership status ID).

[Here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26064/i-keep-getting-payment-instrument-not-valid-when-trying-to-import-contributions) is the similar post that might help to find solution for your question.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: I knew that error meant it didn't like the field contents.  However I didn't put some random value in there.  Instead I set membership to the status I wanted, exported it, then copied what it was set to the 700 members I wanted to cancel.

Comment: Agreed while exporting it export with membership status label so you will need to and replace it with name or id